# Deleting a file from sharepoint using web service

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to delete a file from a sharepoint document library.
My application is in C#, which uses the web services of sharepoint.
Would like to know how this can be done.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Delete a Document in SharePoint using Web Services**

1.Add Web Reference to http://[your site]/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

2.You need **Document ID, Library Name, and Url** to the document to be deleted

```
var spWebServiceLists = "http://[your site]/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
var listService = new Lists
{
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
    Url = spWebServiceLists
};

string id = 10;
string library = @"Shared Documents";
string url = @"http://[your site]/Shared Documents/Test.docx";
string xml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'>" + 
             "<Field Name='ID'>" + id + "</Field>" +
             "<Field Name='FileRef'>" + HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url) + "</Field>" +
             "</Method>";

/*Get Name attribute values (GUIDs) for list and view. */
System.Xml.XmlNode ndListView = listService.GetListAndView(library, "");
string strListID = ndListView.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["Name"].Value;
string strViewID = ndListView.ChildNodes[1].Attributes["Name"].Value;

/*Create an XmlDocument object and construct a Batch element and its
attributes. Note that an empty ViewName parameter causes the method to use the default view. */
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
System.Xml.XmlElement batchElement = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
batchElement.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
batchElement.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
batchElement.SetAttribute("ViewName", strViewID);

/*Specify methods for the batch post using CAML. To update or delete, 
specify the ID of the item, and to update or add, specify 
the value to place in the specified column.*/
batchElement.InnerXml = xml;

XmlNode item;
item = listService.UpdateListItems(library, batchElement);
```

I just tested this code and works well.

For more information please see following links

[Lists.UpdateListItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[How to: Update List Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you work with SharePoint 2010, you can use CSOM to access SharePoint web services. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539976.aspx) could be helpful to execute crud operations. If you work with SharePoint 2013 there is also CSOM API, it has similar funcitonality as in 2010.