# Deleting File from SharePoint List in Java

Tags: java, sharepoint, soap

I'm trying to delete a file from a Sharepoint list in Java and running into some issues. I'm using a batch element described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

I'm able to make the request, but the results that come back are null and the file is not deleted (I don't get any errors).

Here is the code for the UpdateListItems.Update that I'm using:

```
    UpdateListItems.Updates updates = new UpdateListItems.Updates();
    updates.getContent().add(this.generateXmlNode(      
        "<Batch PreCalc='True' OnError='Continue' ListVersion='1' ListName='" + spMoveRequest.getListName() + "'>" +
            "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'>" +
            "<Field Name='ID'>5</Field>" +//this must be where we   specify the file
            "</Method>" +
        "</Batch>"
    ));
```

I'm then making a method call on the listSoap object like this:

```
    UpdateListItemsResult updateResult = listSoap.updateListItems("<my list name here>", updates);
```

I've also tried many variations like using the GUID instead of the actual list name and using

```
    <Field Name='FileRef'><my file url here></Field>
```

to identify the file.

Nothing seems to be working, and I'm not getting any useful feedback either.

The generateXmlNode method that I'm using looks like this:

```
        protected Node generateXmlNode(String sXML) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document documentOptions = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(sXML)));
    Node elementOptions = documentOptions.getDocumentElement();
    return elementOptions;

}
```

but I've used this in the past when retrieving sharepoint lists without problems.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395038/deleting-a-file-from-sharepoint-using-web-service)

Haven't tried it yet but may work.

Comment: Jeff's link could be helpful and you may want to compare that code's output with that of yours using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). If you have access to the server logs you should take a look there also.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution is to use **HTTP DELETE method** to delete a file directly to the Sharepoint with NTLMv2 authentication

For that you can use **Apache HTTP Client**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And to permit NTLMv2 authentication you need **JCIF** library.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>jcifs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcifs</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

First we need to write a wrapper to permit Apache HTTP Client to use JCIF for NTLMv2 support :

```
public final class JCIFSEngine implements NTLMEngine {

    private static final int TYPE_1_FLAGS =
            NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_56
            | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128
            | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM2
            | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
            | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET;

    @Override
    public String generateType1Msg(final String domain, final String workstation)
            throws NTLMEngineException {
        final Type1Message type1Message = new Type1Message(TYPE_1_FLAGS, domain, workstation);
        return Base64.encode(type1Message.toByteArray());
    }

    @Override
    public String generateType3Msg(final String username, final String password,
            final String domain, final String workstation, final String challenge)
            throws NTLMEngineException {
        Type2Message type2Message;
        try {
            type2Message = new Type2Message(Base64.decode(challenge));
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            throw new NTLMEngineException("Invalid NTLM type 2 message", exception);
        }
        final int type2Flags = type2Message.getFlags();
        final int type3Flags = type2Flags
                & (0xffffffff ^ (NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_DOMAIN | NtlmFlags.NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SERVER));
        final Type3Message type3Message = new Type3Message(type2Message, password, domain,
                username, workstation, type3Flags);
        return Base64.encode(type3Message.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ntlm.html)

The main code to execute HTTP DELETE with authentication:

```
    try {

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

        //Register JCIF NTLMv2 to manage ntlm auth.
        httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new AuthSchemeFactory() {
            @Override
            public AuthScheme newInstance(HttpParams hp) {
                return new NTLMScheme(new JCIFSEngine());
            }
        });

        //Provide login/password
        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                AuthScope.ANY,
                new NTCredentials([LOGIN], [PASSWORD], "", [DOMAIN]));
        //Create HTTP PUT Request   

        HttpPut request = new HttpDelete("http://[server]/[site]/[folder]/[fileName]");         
        return httpclient.execute(request);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      //...
    }
```

Linked question to upload a file to Sharepoint  : [How do I upload a document to SharePoint with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314258/how-do-i-upload-a-document-to-sharepoint-with-java/16188830#16188830)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look of this project i've developed to provide a working sharepoint rest api client usable in a very easy way. Take a look in github here:

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java